# Is there a characterization of tempered functions whose Fourier transforms are also tempered functions?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, schwartz-distributions

A *tempered function* on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a locally integrable function that is tempered as a distribution, i.e. $L^1_{loc}\cap\mathcal{S}'$ is the space of tempered functions.

[This MSE question asked for a characterization of tempered functions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34696/which-functions-are-tempered-distributions)

Not every tempered function has a tempered function as its Fourier transform, e.g. the constant function $1$ has the delta distribution $\delta_0$ as its Fourier transform.

My question is, is there a nice characterization of tempered functions whose Fourier transforms are also tempered functions, i.e.

$$ \{ f \in L^1_{loc}\cap\mathcal{S}' : \hat{f} \in L^1_{loc}\cap\mathcal{S}' \} \quad \text{?}$$

Comment: I would try using the fact that Fourier gives a ¨duality" between multiplication by a coordinate ad derivation with respect to that coordinate.